# I am facing a problem that when I try to link the project to Firebase, I see this error

Tags: firebase, flutter-dependencies

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 5,580ms.
W/DynamiteModule( 8056): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/example.shopap( 8056): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 34408(1709KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 2498KB/4186KB, paused 40us total 138.555ms
I/DynamiteModule( 8056): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 8056): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8056): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8056): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8056): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 8056): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@ed11225
E/flutter ( 8056): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-email] The email address is badly formatted.
E/flutter ( 8056): #0      catchPlatformException (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:20:3)
E/flutter ( 8056): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter ( 8056): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter ( 8056): #3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:159:20)
E/flutter ( 8056): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:694:47)
E/flutter ( 8056): #5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:715:24)
E/flutter ( 8056): #6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:534:5)
E/flutter ( 8056): #7      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:15)
E/flutter ( 8056): #8      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart)
E/flutter ( 8056): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8056): #9      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:287:47)
E/flutter ( 8056): #10     FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:186:31)
E/flutter ( 8056): #11     FirbaseAuthentication.register (package:shopapp/authentication/firebase_auth.dart:16:36)
E/flutter ( 8056): #12     _AuthTestState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:shopapp/main.dart:114:58)
E/flutter ( 8056): #13     _AuthTestState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:shopapp/main.dart:111:28)
E/flutter ( 8056): #14     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
E/flutter ( 8056): #15     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
E/flutter ( 8056): #16     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 8056): #17     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:504:11)
E/flutter ( 8056): #18     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282:5)
E/flutter ( 8056): #19     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:217:7)
E/flutter ( 8056): #20     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:475:9)
E/flutter ( 8056): #21     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter ( 8056): #22     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
E/flutter ( 8056): #23     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter ( 8056): #24     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
E/flutter ( 8056): #25     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
E/flutter ( 8056): #26     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter ( 8056): #27     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter ( 8056): #28     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 8056): #29     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 8056): #30     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter ( 8056): #31     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1196:13)
E/flutter ( 8056): #32     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter ( 8056): #33     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
E/flutter ( 8056): #34     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:275:10)
E/flutter ( 8056): #35     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:184:5)
E/flutter ( 8056):
```

Comment: please provide more information so that some one can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

FlutterFire has undergone some [updates](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/) that include breaking changes if you're installing for the first time or migrating. What appears to be happening here is that the new packages expect to see updated Google Play packages on the emulator. However, simply installing the updated OS alone doesn't update the Google Play packages by default.

In Android Studio (it's easier there and VSC), open the "SDK Manager" and navigate to Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK as shown below. See below as an example regarding Android 9.0. You must click "Show Package Details" in the bottom right corner.
[image: Show Package Details Unchecked]

When that is done you will see something like the following. If not already done, close the emulator. Then make sure that the "Google Play" Images are checked. Then apply and install. Restart your emulator and run/debug again. This error should go away.
[image: Show Package Details Checked]